# Can Salesforce run in an on Premises Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: architecture, salesforce, docker-container

I am in charge of setting up Kubernetes for my IT Department.  I am getting close to being done and I presented it yesterday.

I got a question asking if Kubernetes could be leveraged with Salesforce.  I don't know much about Salesforce, so I am unsure.  I thought Salesforce was a hosted product.  Meaning it was something you can't use outside of Salesforce's platform.  But I don't really know and as such I don't want to say "yes" or "no" yet.

Can a Salesforce website run in a Docker Container?  Can it run in an on-premises Kubernetes Cluster?  (Maybe there is a way to connect the cluster with the Salesforce platform?)

Answer (score 2):

No.
Salesforce is proprietary software, they do not release the source code and you can't put it on say LAMP stack. You can connect to their APIs though. Push, pull + cometd, over SOAP or REST. There are commandline tools for deployment of custom code on top of the core platform and data loads or you can connect via Azure Data Factory, Informatica, Mulesoft, Biztalk...

The server-side programming language is called Apex (but it's not Oracle's APEX), it's bit Java-like but it wouldn't compile to Java without extra steps. The underlying database is (or at least used to be) mainly Oracle for "normal" use cases and Apache Solr for full text search. Some older elements of UI can still be seen having "jsp" in filenames but you don't write Java Servlet Pages directly, "Visualforce pages" probably also go through some precompilation steps.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/starting_force_com/starting_understanding_arch and https://www.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/g-cloud/services/757663403510682 might help a bit too?